# I get “Terminated due to timeout” in some test cases in hackerRank,how do I solve this?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I'm trying to solve this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) in HackerRank, but I get timed out error in some test cases. any suggestions?
the following is my code; 
most test cases work, but others time out.

```
public class Solution
{
    static int[] rotation(int[] arr)
    {
        int[] rot = new int[arr.length];
        rot[0] = arr[arr.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, rot, 1, arr.length - 1);
        return rot;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int k = in.nextInt();
        int q = in.nextInt();
        int[] T = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            T[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        int[] indexes = new int[q];
        for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
            indexes[j] = in.nextInt();
        }
        in.close();

        // Rotations
        for (int ai = 0; ai < k; ai++) {
            T = rotation(T);
        }

        // Queries
        for (int qi = 0; qi < q; qi++) {
            System.out.println(T[indexes[qi]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it with ArrayList and LinkedList instead of arrays. but the same result.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, in the input format section it says I would have in the first line of input n, k and q, then the table items. followed by q lines containing the m indexes that I will output. that's what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe rotating the array in-place instead of creating a new one for each rotation?

```
static void rotation(int[] arr)
{
    int temp = arr[arr.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length - 1);
    arr[0] = temp;
}
```

And then later:

```
T = rotation(T);
```

Becomes:

```
rotation(T);
```

You could also optimize for the case where *k* is less than *n*, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you if you need it.